# Loading image in background not applying CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me? I'm using a script to set the image when it has loaded but the style is not being applied together.

```
$('img[data-src]').each(function() {
   var img = $(this);
   var newimg = new Image();
   newimg.src = img.attr('data-src');
   newimg.setAttribute('class', img.attr('data-src'));
   newimg.onload = function() {
   img.replaceWith(newimg);
   };
});
```

I can't put here the HTML & CSS styles because every *< img >* tag has custom style, so I need make this script above works to inherit styles.

What should I do to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are creating a new element which does not have the same `class` and `style` attributes. Just copy them to the new element.

```
$('img[data-src]').each(function() {
   var img = $(this);
   var newimg = new Image();
   newimg.src = img.attr('data-src');
   newimg.setAttribute('class', img.attr('class'));
   newimg.setAttribute('style', img.attr('style'));
   newimg.onload = function() {
   img.replaceWith(newimg);
   };
});
```